# mysql: sub-query return more than 1 rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, subquery

I was trying to solve this question given below by using the subquery in MySQL but can't find a solution as it's showing subquery returns more than one row.

**Problem Statement:**  Display the emp name with their salaries and their managers and managers
      salary.
Display those only employees whose managers were hired after them.

```
select w.ename employee, w.SAL woSal, m.ename manager, m.SAL mSal
from emp w, emp m
where w.mgr = m.empno and
(SELECT E1.ENAME  
FROM EMP E1, EMP E2
WHERE E1.MGR=E2.EMPNO and ( E1.hiredate<E2.hiredate));
```

Comment: It simply means that your sub-query needs more conditions in the where clause so that it returns one row. for any further clarifications please don't hesitate to ask me again

Comment: what is 'mgr' column contains. Please add the schema and sample data

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a subquery - just add the condition on the hiredate to the join condition. Also note that implicit joins (using more than one table in the `from` clause) is considered deprecated, and you'd probably be better off rewriting it as an explicit join:

```
SELECT w.ename employee, w.SAL woSal, m.ename manager, m.SAL mSal
FROM   emp w
JOIN   emp m
WHERE  w.mgr = m.empno and w.hiredate < m.hiredate
```